# ¿ Cómo parar la cuenta atrás de mi aplicación cuando salgo de ella?

Tags: android

Tengo una cuenta atrás dentro de mi aplicación pero quiero que si pulso el botón de " Home button " la cuenta atrás se me pare, para que no siga la aplicación en segundo plano ejecutándose. No quiero que me paséis el esquema típido de onStop(), onResume();, el de las flechas y cubos de colores, pues vengo aquí para que me ayudéis y dar un empujón pues no se interpretar muy bien debido a mi experiencia ese esquema.

Yo he probado lo siguiente sin resultado alguno, habiendo leído que tras un onStop(); venía un Restart o Destroy, elegí Destroy para que no siguiera ejectutándose pero nada....

```
protected void onStop(){

onDestroy();

}
```

y sustituyendo onDestroy(); por finish(); y quitando onStop() y poniendo Destroy y Pause y finish y desesperado pobré mucho pero sin éxito... el código de la cuenta atrás es esta, he intentado hacer timer.finish(); pero timer está declarado en el método onCreate y nada...

```
public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {

    public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);

    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)

    @Override ///////CUENTA ATRÁS
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        long millis = millisUntilFinished;
        String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
        System.out.println(hms);
        textViewTime.setText(hms);  
        textViewTimeotro.setText(hms);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

En el método donde desees detener el timer, por ejemplo `onPause()`, simplemente llama a cancelar la instancia de [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) mediante el método [cancel()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)  :

```
myCountDownTimer.cancel();
```

Realizarías algo como esto:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
   super.onPause();
   myCountDownTimer.cancel();  
}
```

Te recomiendo revisar la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html).

Comment: .cancel no me la acepta... de todas formas revisare documentacion,gracias.

Comment: tu instancia que extiende de CountDownTimer debería tener ese método, ¿como que no lo acepta? ¿puedes agregar como inicializas el timer?

Answer (score 0):

El metodo onStop() no siempre se ejecuta cuando apretas el boton de home, deberias utilizar el metodo onPause() que se ejecuta siempre, te dejo un ejemplo:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
   super.onPause();
   myCountDownTimer.cancel();  
}
```